# running a perl script at specific times

Tags: perl

Is it possible to write a Perl script which runs another Perl script at specific times? 
In fact I want to run my script at specific times forever using another Perl script, i.e. at XX:XX O'clock (for example 12:00) the script runs **automatically** and x-minutes (for example 15 min or 60 min) later it runs again and this procedure continues forever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is definitely possible to write a Perl script that spawns of other scripts at specific times, your needs might be better served by already existing systems such as [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or [at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(Unix)) or the Windows task scheduler if you're on Windows.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. Of course I had heard about the Windows task scheduler, but I wanted to make sure that there is another way or not.